# Formatted code in the edit window does not format properly in the public view of the post

Tags: support, bug

[Link to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978344/given-this-java-code-sample-do-i-have-a-rudimentary-understanding-of-inner-clas)

You can see the code isn't formatting properly in the public view. using the {} icon or manually keying spaces has no effect.

People are griping that I need to learn how to format code, so it's not just my display.

[image: screen shot.]

Comment: Looks OK to me. What browser and OS are you on?

Comment: Win 7, IE8, if you check the comments on the page, that user was having issues viewing it as well. What are YOU using? I'll have to switch to that.

Comment: I use Chrome. We don't officially support IE8 anymore.

Comment: Oh, and it looked fine to me too when I submitted the question, it was left justified after I refreshed the page. Ugh.

Comment: I use chrome at home. Bet it'll be fine there. Sigh. Technology.